# How to add an eventlistner for a click on a list?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to toggle check on a li target but every time I try, I get the error

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null."

From what I can gather, it might be part of the JavaScript or html but I can't tell. So, what is another way or potential solve to properly adding an eventlistner to the list target.

JavaScript Function

```
document.getElementById("tasks").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    if (e.target.nodeName && e.target == "LI") {
        e.target.classList.toggle("checked");
    }
});
```

HTML Code

```
<form name="todolist" id="list">    
    <ul id="tasks">
        <li class="checked">                    
            One
        </li>
        <li>
            Two
        </li>
    </ul>   
</form>
```

Comment: your code works without errors on jsfiddle for me.

Comment: Interesting, it doesn't seem to work in my code. I'm not sure what is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your code is running before the DOM is fully loaded. You can either place your code at the bottom of the body or wrap your code with [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event).

You can try with `querySelectorAll()` and `forEach()` like the following way:

```css
.checked{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    var list = document.querySelectorAll('#tasks li');
    list.forEach(function(el){
      el.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        this.classList.toggle("checked");
      });
    });
  });
</script>

<form name="todolist" id="list">
  <ul id="tasks">
    <li class="checked">
        One
    </li>
    <li>
        Two
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

Comment: Your code works but when I add it to my code, it doesn't. I'm not sure why? Could it be because of how I'm checking the list? I don't get any error either.

Comment: @Harsh, is it still the same error? Please try the updated answer:)

Comment: Nice, this seemed to work! So basically, I needed to reload the DOM for the checklist to work if I'm understanding this correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Wrap your code with in **window.onload** function to make sure element is loaded properly.

```
window.onload=function(){
document.getElementById("tasks").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            if (e.target.nodeName && e.target == "LI") {
            e.target.classList.toggle("checked");
        }
});
}
```

Comment: for this "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null."  it will work

Answer (score -1):

You have an issue with the if statement, it should be

```
//e.target.nodeName == "LI"

<form name="todolist" id="list">

    <ul id="tasks">
        <li class="checked">

            One
        </li>
        <li>
            Two
        </li>
    </ul>


    <script>
    document.getElementById("tasks").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        console.log(e.target.nodeName)
        if (e.target.nodeName && e.target.nodeName == "LI") {

        e.target.classList.toggle("checked");
    }
});
    </script>
```